# Fixed Positioning on iOS 5

Tags: css, ios5, jquery-mobile, css-position

Are there any solutions to the `position: fixed;` problem on iOS 5 while scrolling? So that the fixed element doesn't briefly scroll with the document, because of the DOM freeze during scrolling.

Comment: Is this question jQuery Mobile related?

Comment: Not really, jQuery Mobile is working around the issue: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/

Comment: I'm asking, because if it has to do with jQuery Mobile, then you may get better responses if you add jquery-mobile as a tag.

Comment: "briefly scroll with the document" You mean that jittery movement that happens as you scroll?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue anymore as of iOS5.  No more need for iScroll or whatever.

Furthermore, you can get "native" style bouncy scrolling by adding

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

to your css sheet.

There are a few problems with it still though, at this point AFAIK.